# Seeking title of short story that ran in Playboy (or Maxim?) about New York City's future rise and fall over the next century

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, post-apocalyptic, timeline

Need the title of a short story that ran in Playboy (or Maxim) about four years ago (late 2010-early 2011).  The subject of the story concerned a single brownstone building that lays witness to the rise and fall of a future New York, starting in the present-day and continuing into the next 100-150 years.  Elements of the story include rising sea levels, a sea wall of shipping containers built around the city, asteroid mining leading to a second 'Golden Age', a terrible plague that ravages the planet from a pathogen brought back from the asteroid belt, religious zealots burning cities across the country, and the rebirth of Manhattan as - at first - pastoral farm country and ultimately developing into a city again.  This is what I remembered of the story, though the title and author have eluded me.  Any idea?  Thanks.

Comment: Playboy still has stories in it?

Comment: I only read Playboy for the sci-fi short stories too.

Comment: Surprisingly enough, and it was actually a fairly decent story...

Comment: Playboy pays considerably more than guild minimum and therefore gets high quality submissions. Several authors have written about being pleased to realize that they've written something suitable for the venue because that implies an unusually high payoff for a short-story.

Comment: It looks very like ["New York 2140"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_2140), and also like "2312" by Kim Stanley Robinson. Could be even some initial version in a form of a short story.